# Regex for both negative and positive values in dash-separated string

Tags: c#, regex, match

I'm reading weight and dimension **dash-separated** values from serial port.

This is what incoming data look like right now:

```
-15.0cm-47.8cm-83.1cm:  0.115 kg
```

And this is my pattern for it

```
@"(\d+\.\d+)"
```

However, sometimes one of those values can be negative as well, for example

```
--15.0cm-47.8cm--83.1cm: 0.115 kg.
```

My question is how I can get both negative and positive values at the same time? My expected output for the above string is `[ "-15.0", "47.8", "-83.1", "0.115"]`.

Comment: Wait does the example have negative values, or does it delimit values with a dash?

Comment: Example is dash seperated

Comment: So if you got negative values it would look like `--6.24cm--5.5cm--10cm:  -25.0 kg`?

Comment: Yes I know, thanks for warning but I'm not getting negative values yet. It's jut prevention.

Comment: @TheNewBegining: I asked you for exact expected output, but you said it was working well, and I removed the comment. If you need more help, please feel free to drop a comment below my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a lookbehind pattern to make sure there is a "dash" before another one (that will get consumed, i.e. added to the match value):

```
(?:(?<=-)-)?\d+\.\d+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3c%3d-%29-%29%3f%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b&i=--15.0cm-47.8cm--83.1cm%3a+0.115+kg) against a `--15.0cm-47.8cm--83.1cm: 0.115 kg` string:

[image]

Here, `(?:(?<=-)-)?` is an optional non-capturing group that matches a `-` that is preceded with another `-`. The `\d+\.\d+`  matches 1+ digits, `.` and again 1 or more digits.

C# code:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?:(?<=-)-)?\d+\.\d+")
          .Cast<Match>()
          .Select(m => m.Value)
          .ToList();
```

Comment: This wouldn't work since the data is apparently dash delimited (it would always pick up stuff as negative).

Comment: People call the `-` a minus, a dash, a hyphen... Yes. And OP confirmed it worked (the comment was removed after accepting the answer). To match any "dash", one can replace `-` in the pattern with `\p{Pd}`.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming the dash delimiter is the same character as the minus sign and not one of the other dash characters.

Comment: Yeah guys sorry it was my fault... This is what incoming data look like right now `-15.0cm-47.8cm-83.1cm:  0.115 kg`  and it is dash seperated. But sometimes one of those values could be negative as well like for example `--15.0cm-47.8cm--83.1cm:  0.115 kg`. My question was that if I need multiple patterns to get both negative and positive values at the same time.I'm sorry that I caused misunderstanding.

Comment: So, you need to get `[ "-15.0", "47.8", "-83.1", "0.115"]` from `--15.0cm-47.8cm--83.1cm: 0.115 kg`?

Comment: Yes and I have tested. It seems working correctly now. Thanks again